# When does an equation of this type have a closed-form solution?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, ordinary-differential-equations, functions

Suppose I have an equation of the form

$f(x) + a x f'(x) + b = 0.$

**Note: I am not looking for a general solution to this equation. I am not interested in solving an ODE of this type! Read below.**

I am looking for functions $f(x)$ that let me solve for $x$ explicitly (they need *not* be true for all $x$, so we are not looking at a differential equation per se!).

So far I could just come up with

$f(x) = p x^r + q$, $\ \ \ \ \ \ r\neq 0,$

which has the trivial solution $x^* = \left(-\frac{b+q}{p(1+ar)}\right)^{\frac{1}{r}}$.

Another idea is to solve for the differential equations

$f(x) = \kappa * \left(x f'(x)\right)^2 + C\ \ \ $ and

$f(x) = \kappa * \left(x f'(x)\right)^{1/2} + C$.

Inserting either function into the original equation will lead to a quadratic equation in $x f'(x)$ which implies two solutions for $x f'(x)$. With some "luck", these might be explicitly solvable for $x$.

However, I'm wondering whether there is a more systematic approach -- and more importantly, whether I have overlooked some other simple examples.

Many thanks in advance!

Edit: I just realized that $f(x) = p ln(qx) + r$ also allows for an explicit solution $x^*$.

Comment: [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%27+%2B+a+x+y+%2B+b+%3D+0) finds a general solution of the differential equation.

Comment: @Martin: Are you looking the explicit solution? As, I have found above you hadn't solved the OE. Am I right?

Comment: @lhf: First, I think you should have entered $y + a x y' + b = 0$, which yields a much simpler general solution. *However*, as indicated in the text, I am not looking for a general solution to this type of equation! I am just looking for functions $f(x)$ that let me solve the equation explicitly for $x$ (as a function of the parameters $a$ and $b$). The equation *need not* be satisfied in general!

Comment: @ Babak S.: As indicated in the text, I am not looking for a solution to the ODE. I am just interested in types of functions $f(x)$ that let me solve for $x$ explicitly (as a function of the parameters $a$ and $b$).

Answer (score 0):

Let $y=f(x)$. The equation is rewritten as:

$$\frac{dy}{y+b}=\frac{dx}{-ax}$$
Therefore:
$$Ln(y+b)=-\frac{1}{a}Ln(x)+C$$
$$y=e^{-\frac{1}{a}Ln(x)+C_{1}}-b$$
or:
$$y=C_{2}x^{-\frac{1}{a}}-b$$
or:
$$x=C_{3}(y+b)^{-a}$$

Comment: Thanks for your effort! However, unless I'm misunderstanding something, this is *not* the problem I am facing and the answer I am looking for. Please compare with my original question (edited for emphasizing my problem).

Comment: @MartinObradovits Ok, as you see the solution to ODE lets you to derive $x$ in terms of $y=f(x)$. You are free to choose any rule for $f(x)$ and put it in the last equation above.

Comment: I don't think this helps me much, as you still impose that the first equation has to be fulfilled for all x. I don't need this property. I am not interested in a solution to an ODE. I want properties on $f(x)$ (where $f(x)$ need not solve the first equation for all $x$!) that allow me to find an explicit solution $x^*(a,b)$.